Nhibernate Invalid cast after Refresh newly created object
I have a class called Invoice and 2 other related classed that because it's a legacy system we have some different implementations in one:
InvoiceDetails
    ManyToOne(k => k.Invoice, m =>
    {
        m.Column("Invoice_id");
        m.Class(typeof(Invoice));
        m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore);
    });

and another
InvoiceCustomProperties
<many-to-one name="Invoice" column="Invoice_id" class="Core.Invoices.Invoice" />

When we add a new invoice and then add new InvoiceDetails, then we refresh it (we are using a generic method) it works fine.
BUT when we add a new invoice and then add new InvoiceCustomProperties, then we refresh it it breask with an exception like the following:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Core.Invoices.Invoice' to type 'Core.Invoices.GroupedInvoice' that has no relationship or reference in either of the two tables
(yes GroupedInvoice inherits from Invoice)
any hints would be appreciated.
Ou to refresh we are using
 CurrentPersistenceContext.Session.NHibernateSession.Refresh()

